# Deploy error on AppCloud with ruby-debug19 in text, development environments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, engineyard

In EY AppCloud, even when you run in development env, they run bundler --without development and test. My Gemfile contains this

```
group :test, :development do
  gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'
end
```

and when I deploy I get this error:

```
Successfully installed engineyard-serverside-1.4.2
1 gem installed
~> Deploying revision a01f92c migrating to new FactoryGirl
~> Pushing code to all servers
~> Starting full deploy
~> Copying to /data/eg/releases/20110821184344
~> Ensuring proper ownership
~> Gemfile detected, bundling gems
~> Symlinking configs
ln: creating symbolic link `/data/eg/releases/20110821184344/config/database.yml': File exists
~> Migrating: cd /data/eg/releases/20110821184344 && PATH=/data/eg/releases/20110821184344/ey_bundler_binstubs:$PATH RAILS_ENV=development RACK_ENV=development MERB_ENV=development rake db:migrate --trace
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- ruby-debug
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.15/lib/bundler.rb:120:in `require'
/data/eg/releases/20110821184344/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/data/eg/releases/20110821184344/Rakefile:5:in `require'
/data/eg/releases/20110821184344/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
/data/eg/shared/bundled_gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
/data/eg/shared/bundled_gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
/data/eg/shared/bundled_gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:495:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/data/eg/shared/bundled_gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in load_rakefile'
/data/eg/shared/bundled_gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/data/eg/shared/bundled_gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `load_rakefile'
/data/eg/shared/bundled_gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:61:in `block in run'
/data/eg/shared/bundled_gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/data/eg/shared/bundled_gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:59:in `run'
/data/eg/shared/bundled_gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/bin/rake:32:in `<top (required)>'
/data/eg/releases/20110821184344/ey_bundler_binstubs/rake:16:in `load'
/data/eg/releases/20110821184344/ey_bundler_binstubs/rake:16:in `<main>'
~> [Attention] Maintenance page still up, consider the following before removing:
 * any deploy hooks ran, be careful if they were destructive
 * any migrations ran, be careful if they were destructive
 * your old code is still symlinked as current
Failed deployment recorded in AppCloud
Deploy failed
```

If I comment out the gem 'ruby-debug19' line in Gemfile it works. But it should be ignoring that anyway since as mentioned, AppCloud ignores test, development env gems. It works locally in both cases. Can anyone think at all what might cause this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is because `config/application.rb` calls `Bundler.require` with a few group names, one being `Rails.env`. You `RAILS_ENV` on the command line is `development`, which means `Bundler.require` is trying to load the `development` group and require things in it, including `ruby-debug`. Since the bundle has been installed the `development` group, it breaks.

Probably best to use `development` for `RAILS_ENV` when running your app locally and either `staging` or `production` for your app on AppCloud.

Comment: Why would EY do this then? It seems like in every case that you put something in the development group only, the app would fail to launch (when in development mode on EY) b/c it won't install those gems that application.rb then tries to require? Also, I'm not able to reproduce this locally after running 'bundle install --without development test'. That seems odd. Thanks!

Comment: Why would EY do what? I'm able to reproduce it locally: https://gist.github.com/1162178. It does seem to only break when `:require => 'ruby-debug19'` is present, though. That could be a bug in bundler.

Answer (score 0):

AppCloud does not install the 'development' or 'test' groups by default. You would need to configure that in an `eydeploy.rb` file. You can find documentation about Installation Groups at http://docs.engineyard.com/bundler-tips-for-appcloud.html.